# Merge PDF files with PDF Creator via VBA

Tags: ms-access, pdf, vba

I'm using the example code of [PDFCreator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/) to create pdf's from my Access (2003) reports via VBA. This works fine, but now I want to merge several pdf's into a single one. PDF Creator is able to this via the Wait-button in the dialog, but I want to do this silent.
Any ideas how to achieve this? I can't find sufficient documentations of the PDFCreator-class.

Comment: For what it's worth, when I wanted to do this, I couldn't make it work. But I was creating PDFs by automating Word, so there might have been something wrong with that. My eventual solution was to import the component Word documents into a new file and then output a single PDF from that. This may be impossible with your setup, unfortunately, but it depends on what you're outputting as PDF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the VB Script options in the C:\Program Files\PDFCreator\Scripts folder.   Figure out which one you need.  With a bit of work you can convert the VBScript code to VBA code.

Comment: Found an example in c:\program files\pdfcreator\com\windows scripting host\vbscripts\combinejobs.vbs
The trick is to set cPrinterStop to True, then print all desired reports, then call cConbineAll and set cPrinterStop to False.

Answer (score 0):

The Scripts folder currently has VBA script for word. This will will slightly differently in Access. There is also bug that may effect you:

https://forums.pdfforge.org/t/any-idea-if-the-vba-bug-works-every-second-time-will-be-adressed/15668