# PDFCreator merge multiple pdf files into one

Tags: pdf, printing, vb6, pdf-generation

I am using PDFCreator to combine multiple files into one PDF file.
The code looks like this:

```
dim pdfJob as new PDFCreator.clsPDFCreator

with pdfJob
   .cOption("UseAutosave")=1
   .cOption("UseAutosaveDirectory")=1
   .cOption("AutosaveDirectory")=sPDFPath
   .cOption("AutosaveFilename")="combine.pdf"
   .cOption("Autosaveformat")=0
   .cClearCache
end with

pdfJob.cPrinterStop = true
pdfJob.cPrintFile("c:\1.pdf") 'pdf-reader pops up and freezes until it is closed
sleep(2000)
pdfJob.cPrintFile("c:\2.pdf") 'pdf-reader pops up and freezes until it is closed
sleep(2000)    
pdfJob.cPrintFile("c:\3.pdf") 'pdf-reader pops up and freezes until it is closed        
sleep(2000)

pdfJob.cCombineAll

pdfJob.cPrinterStop = false
```

This code will work perfectly if I print .txt, .doc, but when it comes to PDF, it will stop on each print until we close the pdf reader application (e.g. adobe pdf reader, foxit reader) (stuck on the pdfJob.cPrintfile line) manually (i.e in the case above, we will need to close the pdf reader three times before it will tries to combine the pdf).

Can I ask is there a way we could bypass this manual closing step, as I would to automate the process.

Note: If we set pdfJob.cPrinterStop as false, application window will still pop up, but it will not hang (just it won't combine the pdfs)

Many thanks

Comment: If anyone find this check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5338401/merge-pdf-files-with-pdf-creator-via-vba

Answer (score 2):

We do something similar but with a different tool, [PDFtk](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/).

I'm not personally familiar with PDFCreator, but it seems like it's using the OS registered .pdf file handler application and it's that application that is causing your issue.  If you need to stick with PDFCreator, you'll have to research whatever PDF app you'll need your app to interact with to get it to close (or alternatively you could create code to programatically terminate that app)

With PDFtk, it opens the .pdf files on it's own and merges them without needing to open another app to handle the .pdf contents.